# What is the right way to transform multiple columns of a DataFrame in place in Julia?

Tags: dataframe, julia

How should I apply a function to every element of some columns in place?

```
julia> using DataFrames

julia> df = DataFrame(Time = [3, 4, 5], TopTemp = [70, 73, 100], BottomTemp = [50, 55, 80])
3×3 DataFrame
 Row │ Time   TopTemp  BottomTemp 
     │ Int64  Int64    Int64      
─────┼────────────────────────────
   1 │     3       70          50
   2 │     4       73          55
   3 │     5      100          80

julia> fahrenheit_to_celsius(x) = Int(round((x - 32) * 5 / 9))
fahrenheit_to_celsius (generic function with 1 method)
```

This works for one column, but I'm not sure it is the best method.

```
julia> transform!(df, "TopTemp" => ByRow(fahrenheit_to_celsius), renamecols = false)
3×3 DataFrame
 Row │ Time   TopTemp  BottomTemp 
     │ Int64  Int64    Int64      
─────┼────────────────────────────
   1 │     3       21          50
   2 │     4       23          55
   3 │     5       38          80
```

The same method does not work to convert both columns using a regular expression with broadcasting.

```
julia> transform!(df, r"Temp" .=> ByRow.(fahrenheit_to_celsius), renamecols = false)
ERROR: LoadError: MethodError: no method matching fahrenheit_to_celsius(::Int64, ::Int64)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
transform!(df, names(df, r"Temp") .=> ByRow(fahrenheit_to_celsius), renamecols = false)
```

or

```
df[!, r"Temp"] .= fahrenheit_to_celsius.(df[!, r"Temp"])
```

also note that it is not in-place, but the columns are replaced in both cases above but this is probably what you want in general.

An in-place operation would be:

```
df[:, r"Temp"] .= fahrenheit_to_celsius.(df[!, r"Temp"])
```

but it would fail if `fahrenheit_to_celsius` would change `eltype` of columns.

The fastest should be:

```
foreach(col -> col .= fahrenheit_to_celsius.(col), eachcol(df[!, r"Temp"])))
```

Comment: Are the speeds all similar?

Comment: if the data frame is large they should be similar. The core operation in all cases is performed in the same way. If the data frame is small, but you perform this operation millions of times then probably broadcasting might be a bit faster as it requires less internal logic. If you want to be super fast there is yet another solution that is in place - I have added it to the list.

Comment: another:    `mapcols(col -> col .= fahrenheit_to_celsius.(col), df[!, r"Temp"])`

Comment: For combine passing to sum I needed `combine(df, permutedims(Symbol.(names(df, r"Temp"))) .=> sum, renamecols = false)` to get it right.

Comment: The `combine(df, names(df, r"Temp") .=> sum, renamecols = false)` should work. What error did it produce? In more modern syntax (not available at the time of writing the answer) it would be `combine(df, Cols(r"Temp") .=> sum, renamecols = false)` or `combine(df, Cols(r"Temp") .=> sum => identity)`.